# How to make a PHP object return a non-string?

Tags: php

While reading the documentation for SplEnum, I saw this line of code in the examples:

```
echo new Month(Month::June) . PHP_EOL;
```

And the output of that code is "6".  I don't know whether the value is a string or a number, though.

This made me wonder, can PHP objects return values of types other than string?  I know that I can make my classes return a string by defining the `__toString()` function.  However, if I try to return a value of another type, an exception is thrown.

Is there any way to make an object return a non-string?  I'm interested in a pure-PHP solution, not one that requires compiling an extension, like SplEnum.  (If SplEnum is returning a non-string and a compiled extension is the only way to accomplish that, I'd appreciate a confirmation of that, too.)

Comment: if u need a integer, use `intval()`, if string, just cast it `(string)$val` for example, just use it as a "output function" that returns it

Comment: The answer to this question is pretty short: No. The longer version would be: `__toString()` was originally designed for debugging only. The engine explicitly forbids it to return any other types (so extensions will have a hard time doing this as well). There have been numerous proposals to add functionality like this over the years, but there has yet to be anything approaching a consensus on how it should actually work. That said, operator overloading is likely to be what you actually want - but we don't have that in userland either :-(

Comment: SplTypes are experimental, and they likely won't be included in PHP because they don't solve the autoboxing/unboxing problem.  There is no way to do this without a method/function call to explicitly convert an object to a non-string scalar value.

Comment: Since `echo` emits strings, it's clear that PHP tries to cast the object to string. But it isn't clear whether you're asking for a `__toInt()` magic method or to let `__toString()` return a non-string :-?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you're trying to do. Once returning a String, you can cast it to whatever you like, but __toString() must return an actual string (and there's no __toInt()), per:

[PHP Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

> This method must return a string, as otherwise a fatal E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR level error is emitted."

On a more philosophical note, converting an object to an int may not be a great architectural pattern. You might want to reconsider your design if you're thinking about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `__toString` is that it doesn't make obvious what the format is.

There are many ways you might want to print a Month object: `"Jan"`, `"January"`, `"01"`, `"1"`, `"janvier"`. `__toString` is absolutely the wrong function to use.

There is some merit in using `__toString` when debugging but even then it's questionable.

My recommendation is that you make a function for every output format that you want to support, for example:

```
Month->getMonth(); // returns int(1)
Month->getFormattedMonth("long"); // returns "January"
```